# RCT bridging with react native and objective C

Tags: objective-c, react-native, rctbridge

I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ryardley/4-connect-react-native-to-c-a2809b92095), which is talking about how to communicated from React Native and objective C. I followed the tutorial, and got a good result. The problem started when I wanted to add a new function called sendData. This would be called in JS and it would pass a string, and in objective C, it would receive the string.

But, the bridging wasn't working.

Here is my code:

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(sendData : (NSString*)str,
                 sendData_resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 sendData_rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  BOOL response = [_cppApi sendData];
  resolve(response);
}
```

This code gives the error `No visible @interface for 'CCCppCom' declares the selector 'sendData'` in Xcode. (CCCppCom is a header file)
another function I have, which is getData seems to work fine.

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(getData,
                 resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSString *response = [_cppApi getData];
  resolve(response);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. I checked CCCppCom, and sendData is indeed there.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Mannan Could you just share the complete ```CCCppCom.h``` and ```CCCppCom.m``` files here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using RCT_EXPORT_METHOD instead of RCT_REMAP_METHOD.